# A weighted $W^{2,p}$ estimates

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain and  $u\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$. By the classical $L^p$ theory of second order elliptic equation, we have
$$
\|\nabla^2u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L^p(\Omega)},
$$
where $p\geq 1$, $C$ is a constant dependent of $\Omega$ and independent of $u$.

Now let $g$ be a smooth  function. Define a weighted norm
$$
\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega, |g|)}=\left(\int_\Omega|u|^p|g|dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.
$$
What I want to ask is, whether we have
$$
\|\nabla^2u\|_{L^p(\Omega, |g|)}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L^p(\Omega, |g|)}.
$$
If it does not hold, under what conditions on $g$ we can make this become true?

Comment: If $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$ this is true when the weight $|g|$ is in the Muckhenaupt class $A_p$. It should be the same in $\Omega$.